# When exactly is return value copied

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Let's suppose I have following code:

```
int bar = 0;

struct Foo {
    ~Foo() { bar = 1; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Foo f;
    return bar;
}
```

What will be return value of program? 0 or 1?

Comment: Why on earth would it be undefined behaviour?!

Comment: I don't think that UB paranoia is such a bad thing.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Meh. If this were UB, simple things like `std::lock_guard` wouldn't work, nor would returning unique pointers by value.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't get why lock_guard would not work (could you maybe explain if you have time?) but you are right with the unique pointer

Comment: @Paladin: Because you'd release the lock before you access the shared state! `int get() { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m); return shared_int; }`

Comment: oh, good point, didn't think of that, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [stmt.return]/3:

> The copy-initialization of the returned entity is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before
>   the destruction of local variables (6.6) of the block enclosing the return statement.

So the destructor runs after the return value has been initialized, and the return value is thus 0 on the first call of your function.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic variables are removed in the reverse order to their declaration.

So the return value of the function is established before the call to `~Foo()`.

The return of `foobar` is therefore a very well-defined 0.

Your question would be more interesting if your function returned `int&`.